# What is a function executed by setTimeout called?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout, naming, deferred

I currently use the following function to queue a function call in the event loop:

```
Function.prototype.async = function () {
    setTimeout.bind(null, this, 0).apply(null, arguments);
};
```

This allows me to write code like this:

```
alert.async("This will be displayed later.");
alert("This will be displayed first.");
```

Now I'm planning to include this function in a library I'm writing. However the name `async` seems like an inaccurate description for the function. Technically the function is not executing asynchronously.

So my question is that if a function executed by `setTimeout` is not asynchronous then what is it? How would you describe it?

I believe `defer` would be a more suitable name but I'm not so sure.

Comment: I would probably use `defer` too.

Comment: `process.nextTick()` :P

Comment: Then call them by a generic name like a "callback" or "handler"

Comment: @Chad - That's very node of you, but I'll give it a different name so as to not confuse people. =D

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - It's neither a callback nor a handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMAscript code is executed in the such called *UI thread*, which is running within any Browser implementation. Basically, all *UI updates* and *Javascript code blocks* are shared within that thread (that is also the reason, why long running Javascript code will hang the browsers UI).

However, what `setTimeout` does, is just to queue the **insertion** of your *function* into that *UI thread*. That in turn means, there is no guarantee that your code will actually get executed in *xxx miliseconds*, just that it will get pushed into the queue. If other processes are still running or the browser is busy within the thread, it will not get executed until anything else was processed.

How would I call it ?

*"Deferring execution of ECMAscript code"*

Comment: I think my words got more technical, I was not aware of this much details, just conceptual knowledge, thank you Andy :)

Answer (score 0):

It is executing after the first call is over(back to back),

And binded using `set-timeout`, to start after the first event over.

So it is synchronous (Joined / in flow),

I hope I make sense here :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not asynchronous. It is blocking, it is just blocking later. That is called "deferred" not "async"

Comment: I'm sorry to say but I'm lost trying to decipher the meaning of your sentences MarmiK. Would you be more clear in what you're trying to convey? Hey, that rhymes! =D

Comment: and if the data/event is joined after first event, technically you are also right, as it is delaying the first event,

but it is delayed for joining the event after first event.(so the purpose of delay is to make it async.

I don't want to win here. just making debate :)